# My PhpStrom shows me this warning Unable to parse the file '***.php'

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm new to PhpStorm. My PhpStorm shows me this warning:

> Unable to parse the file '***.php'

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

phpstrom trying to find

> calculate.php

in the same directories. but they were not found.
I see you have a file in the o2 folder

> caculate.php

. so there has a spelling error.